# How do you allow repeats when generating random colors in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

I have a list like this:

```
colors = ["red", "blue", "yellow", "green", "purple", "orange"] 
answers = random.sample(colors, 4)
```

I am having trouble trying to figure out how to allow repeats like red,red,blue,yellow when generating random colors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try

```
[random.choice(colors) for _ in range(4)]
```

Here `random.choice(colors)` picks a single random color from the `colors` list. Using the list comprehension will call the function four times and collect results in a new list.

Example run:

```
>>> colors = ["red", "blue", "yellow", "green", "purple", "orange"] 
>>> import random
>>> [random.choice(colors) for _ in range(4)]
['red', 'green', 'orange', 'orange']
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternative approach (just for fun; I'd actually use `random.choice`) that allows continued use of `random.sample` is to use sequence multiplication so you repeat each option a number of times equal to the number of desired items, ensuring it can (possibly) be selected every time, and definitely available for repeated selection:

```
answers = random.sample(colors * 4, 4)
```

Comment: Granted that this is just for fun, it's probably worth noting that this approach will not have a flat probability distribution between all possible outcomes – "samples" with more duplicates are progressively less likely.

Comment: @ZeroPiraeus: Yar. It's not perfectly even. That could be beneficial in some scenarios, since people looking for random outputs (not crypto random, just random assortments) often don't want to see excessive repeats (it "looks" non-random, even though it's as random as can be) so biasing towards "more random looking" outputs without preventing any given result completely could be a good thing.